# Create a table from a view and sync it with view

Tags: mysql, view, synchronization

How can I sync a table with an existing view in the same mysql database? 
The content of table should be updated if any add, edit or deletes happend to view.

Comment: cant you sync a that view?

Comment: run an `UPDATE` query. What's the problem? BTW, If you want your table to be updated according to the view, maybe your table should be a view.

Comment: Are you looking for an updateable view? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/view-updatability.html

Comment: I am using a view which is to slow for certain operation. I created from this view a table and saw that is more faster than the view it self. What I want is to have a solution that the table is updated if any changes have been made by the view. Without any manually update or add operation.